# Nuxtjs - (firestore is not a function) when accessing firebase from nuxt.config.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

i have this nuxt.config.js

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore'
export default {
//my configs....
  sitemap: {
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    gzip: true,
    routes: async () => {
      var app = firebase.initializeApp({
        //my firebase config
      })
      var firee = app.firestore();
      var posts_collection = await firee.collection("posts").get();
      var links = [];
      links = links.concat(posts_collection.docs.map(v => `posts/post?id=${v.id}`))
      return links;
    }
  },
```

basically i'm getting all my `posts` from my firestore database; and generate a list of links to use them for my `sitemap.xml`.
the code works fine while im serving it on my machine, but after i build and deploy it on a host, i get this error:-

```
ERROR  app.firestore is not a function
at routes (nuxt.config.js:91:23)
at promisifyRoute (node_modules/@nuxtjs/sitemap/lib/cache.js:59:17)
at AsyncCache.load [as _load] (node_modules/@nuxtjs/sitemap/lib/cache.js:18:28)
at AsyncCache.get (node_modules/async-cache/ac.js:63:8)
at internal/util.js:340:30
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at AsyncCache.get (internal/util.js:339:12)
at handler (node_modules/@nuxtjs/sitemap/lib/middleware.js:99:43)
at call (node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
at next (node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
```

## Things i've tried:-

instead of calling my database again, i tried to retrieve the `posts` from my store.js file, as i get a global variable populated with the `posts`, when my website is initiated, but i didn't have luck with accessing store variables, i googled and found this [post][1] which tells me that it's impossible to do that.

---

i also tried to fix the problem with firestore, i tried the other methods of importing firestore/app, such as

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

or

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
```

these didn't work at all.

i printed out the `app` variable to see what is it, and i got this

```js
FirebaseAppImpl {
  _delegate: FirebaseAppImpl {
    _isDeleted: false,
    _options: {
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyB0BoFiJ2LeEVflDnSikVsr4le7i5i8K-k',
      authDomain: 'hedi-bc317.firebaseapp.com',
      projectId: 'hedi-bc317',
      storageBucket: 'hedi-bc317.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '313801605853',
      appId: '1:313801605853:web:eae7a9fee24a7b06535134',
      measurementId: 'G-93L924PZWJ'
    },
    _config: { name: '[DEFAULT]', automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false },
    _name: '[DEFAULT]',
    _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false,
    _container: ComponentContainer { name: '[DEFAULT]', providers: [Map] }
  },
  firebase: <ref *1> {
    __esModule: true,
    initializeApp: [Function: initializeAppCompat],
    app: [Function: app] { App: [Function: FirebaseAppImpl] },
    registerVersion: [Function: registerVersion],
    setLogLevel: [Function: setLogLevel],
    onLog: [Function: onLog],
    apps: [Getter],
    SDK_VERSION: '9.6.10',
    INTERNAL: {
      registerComponent: [Function: registerComponentCompat],
      removeApp: [Function: removeApp],
      useAsService: [Function: useAsService],
      modularAPIs: [Object],
      createFirebaseNamespace: [Function: createFirebaseNamespace],
      extendNamespace: [Function: extendNamespace],
      createSubscribe: [Function: createSubscribe],
      ErrorFactory: [Function: ErrorFactory],
      deepExtend: [Function: deepExtend]
    },
    default: [Circular *1]
  },
  container: ComponentContainer {
    name: '[DEFAULT]',
    providers: Map(12) {
      'platform-logger' => [Provider],
      'heartbeat' => [Provider],
      'fire-core-node-version' => [Provider],
      'fire-core-cjs5-version' => [Provider],
      'fire-js-version' => [Provider],
      'fire-core-compat-version' => [Provider],
      'fire-js-all-app-compat-version' => [Provider],
      'firestore' => [Provider],
      'fire-fst-node-version' => [Provider],
      'fire-fst-cjs2017-version' => [Provider],
      'app' => [Provider],
      'app-compat' => [Provider]
    }
  }
}
```

i see firebase database but no firestore, at this point i don't know what else to do, i'll appreciate any help.
[1]: [Access store in nuxt config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959985/access-store-in-nuxt-config-file)

Comment: You're using `target: 'static'`? Double check the version of Firebase used here, to not be in a limbo syntax-wise.

Comment: i am using firebase 9.6.10 (latest)

Comment: What about the first part?

Comment: @kissu to be honest i didn't understand what `target: 'static'` means, could you please elaborate?

Comment: In your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Comment: @kissu no the website is SSR